# My Transaction is pending for over 20 hours now - initiated a call to the transfer function using Web3

Tags: web3js, tokens, erc-20

I'm making a call to the `transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)` function within the contract through Web3. Here's my code;

`var Contract = web3.eth.contract(ContractABI);
 var ContractHandle = Contract.at(ContractAddress);
 ContractHandle.transfer(toAddress, tokens, {
        from: deductGasFromAddress,
        gasPrice: gasPrice,
        gasAmount: gasAmount
    }, function(error, result) {
        // write something
    });`

I've specified 22 Gwei as the gasPrice, I think that's good enough for a faster transaction. However, it's in pending state for more than 20 hours.

Am I missing something in this regards? Would appreciate any quick help pertaining to this.

Comment: What is the transaction ID?

Comment: @RaghavSood, 0x8670fdeb162568048b12e10c20fe188f379094d6b9b91a89b47cd7d5f0e282c8 is the TX hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x8670fdeb162568048b12e10c20fe188f379094d6b9b91a89b47cd7d5f0e282c8` has a nonce of 6.

Currently, every single transaction from your address is pending, from nonce 0 onwards. Nonce 0 itself has a gas price of 1 gwei, which is a bit lower than the current network average of 3 gwei or so.

Ethereum confirms transactions in order of nonce, so nonce 6 will not confirm until 0 through 5 have confirmed.

You can either wait, or make new transactions for the lower nonces with a higher gas price.

Comment: Thanks Raghav! That makes sense. I was not sure if the transactions are processed in order of nonce. I will try with a different address that doesn't have any previous transaction in pending state. Will keep you informed.

Comment: It worked Raghav! Thank you for your quick help on this.